How can I specify different OIDC authentication for different API in appsync
In appsync authentication method, I can specify multiple Open ID Connect as authentication method. In the schema, I can use @aws_oidc to control which API will use this OIDC to authenticate. My question is how I can set different API to use different OIDC?
For example, I have two Open ID issuer urls, https://oidc1.xxx.com, https://oidc2.xxx.com. I have configured them in my appsync API. I have below Graphql schema:
Query {
  @aws_oidc
  getOrder
}

Mutation {
  @aws_oidc
  addOrder
}

How can I set getOrder to use https://oidc1.xxx.com but addOrder to use https://oidc2.xxx.com?
